# How to get a float from a db in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

My db has a column to save float values.

It works fine when I get float value like 1  or 1.2  or 1.23,

but when I want to get 1.234 ,Cursor.getString returns 1234,and Cursor.getFloat returns 1234.0

I want to get 1.2345 ,Cursor.getString returns 12345 and Cursor.getFloat returns 12345.0

I tried to change db column type to DEC、text、varchar、float but none of them works.

How can I get value correctly?

Comment: How are you storing and reading the values, really? Looks like at some point the `.` get interpreted as grouping separator instead of decimal point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe REAL is what you are looking for http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html